# Merge 2 pandas dataframe using similar data

Tags: python, pandas

I can't find an elegant solution to merge those two datasets:

Let's say I have a first dataset, with temperatures of cities

```
       2016 2017
cityA   23  27
cityB   24  28
```

And another one with a lot of information, but that looks like that:

```
    city    year    other
0   cityA   2016    aa
1   cityB   2017    bb
2   cityA   2016    cc
3   cityB   2017    dd
```

And I would like the following result:

```
     city  year other  temperatures
0   cityA   2016    aa    23
1   cityB   2017    bb    28
2   cityA   2016    cc    23
3   cityB   2017    dd    24
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT : real and more complex dataframes:

dataframe 1 with temperatures
[image]

dataframe 2 with other datas:
[image]

results of the implementation of the answer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for reshape and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), I think with left join:

```
df11 = df1.stack().reset_index()
df11.columns = ['city','year','temperatures']
#if years are strings convert to integers
df11['year'] = df11['year'].astype(int)

df = df2.merge(df11, on=['city','year'], how='left')
print (df)
    city  year other  temperatures
0  cityA  2016    aa            23
1  cityB  2017    bb            28
2  cityA  2016    cc            23
3  cityB  2017    dd            28
```

Comment: thanks for your help, unfortunatly it works well on this example, but not on my real problem. I will try to add more explainations

Comment: I edited my original post with screenshot of the implementation of your solution. As you can see, there is NaN that appear after the merge

Comment: @Roger - You forget cast column year to integers.

Comment: Yes you're right! It works well with the extra line to cast to integers! Thanks a lot for your precious help Jezrael, I wish you a very nice day!

Answer (score 0):

#### melt + merge

You can melt your "pivoted" dataframe, then left merge with your master dataframe. Assumes the year columns in your first dataframe are integers.

```
melted = pd.melt(df1.reset_index(), id_vars='index')

res = df2.merge(melted, left_on=['city', 'year'],
                right_on=['index', 'variable'], how='left')

print(res[['city', 'year', 'other', 'value']])

    city  year other  value
0  cityA  2016    aa     23
1  cityB  2017    bb     28
2  cityA  2016    cc     23
3  cityB  2017    dd     28
```